# Fix "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" WITHOUT screwing up a pom?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

[This](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered#ignore_plugin_goal), and many other posts, suggest to change a pom to get it working, which is quite a bold demand as for a mere plugin. Is it possible to leave pom intact and still do not see those errors?

Best regards,Eugene.

Comment: Ah, and yes, there are still no connectors for my plugin.

Comment: Could you first tell us why you do not want to alter the POM, before asking us to go off on a wild-goose chase?

Comment: well, the reason is obvious - there are usually many contributors to a project which may use different IDEs/plugins, and they don't want to have poms polluted with some unrelated stuff

Comment: I concur with user656449.  I'm a contractor doing some small work on a someone else's project.  Littering the pom with IDE-specific configuration settings is unacceptable.  I still don't understand why this configuration must go into the pom rather than an Eclipse-specific project settings file.  This is a potential show-stopper for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not possible. This in-POM mess is some kind of workaround if you don't want these errors. Unless your plugin somehow provide m2e connector, you don't have really choice. Sorry.

Comment: mmm, sorry, are you m2e developer? If so, I was thinking about some dummy connector which can be used whenever real one is not yet developed. And I hoped such connector already existed :) Is it possible to write one? Or, at least, is it worth trying?

Comment: I'm not m2e developer, but I investigated this stuff few weeks ago. From my research, it's not possible that way.